# How do I call a variable from a function in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In the following code I want to call payment_amount outside of the function, I've tried declaring the variables with var to make them global variables, but I still can't seem to call them outside of the function.

```
var payment_amount;

con.query("SELECT payment_amount FROM transactions LIMIT 1",function(err,payment_amount,fields){

        if(err)throw err;
        payment_amount = JSON.stringify(payment_amount);
        payment_amount = payment_amount.replace('[{"payment_amount":','');
        payment_amount = payment_amount.replace('}]','');
        payment_amount = parseFloat(payment_amount);
        console.log(payment_amount);
        return payment_amount;
        
    });
console.log(payment_amount); //RESULTS IN 'UNDEFINED'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `con.query()` call is likely asynchronous. That means that you're getting to the `console.log()` before the function inside the `.query()` callback is completed. Here are some docs that generally outline how asynchronous code works in JS: [Async docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)

What ORM are you using to get to the database? You can usually find examples on how to use `async/await` for that ORM. The call might end up looking something more like...

```
const getPaymentAmount = async () => {
  try {
    const paymentAmountResult = await con.query("SELECT payment_amount FROM transactions LIMIT 1")
    console.log(paymentAmountResult) // works!

    ///... your parsing code etc.

    return thingYouWantToReturn
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, it didn't print anything in the console.

Comment: Please add what you tried to your original question

Comment: I did, it prints nothing in the console, nor can you retrieve the variable outside of the function

Comment: Please update the original question with what you tried with respect to async/await. The problem is that the code does not wait for con.query to execute before moving onto your console.log(). You need to add an await (like how it's written in my answer above) in order to get the code to wait until the data has been fetched and assigned before moving onto the console.log.